# Failing to authenticate with MongoDB using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've been attempting to add authentication to my mongo database.

So following various tutorials and solving some problems (my server was 2.4 and needed to be upgraded), I was finally able to add a user

I run the server in one shell

```
mongod --dbpath ./
```

then in another I run

```
mongo
use admin
db.createUser({
     user:"user",
     pwd:"pass",
     roles: [{role:"userAdminAnyDatabase", db:"admin"}]
})
```

I get a success message, so then I quit out of both the server and the shell

In another shell I run

```
mongod --dbpath ./ --auth
```

Then I run

```
node server.js
```

Within the server.js file, there is the following code

```
mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/db', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;  
    db.authenticate("user", "pass", function(err, res) {
        if(err) throw err;      
        // code here
    });
});
```

But this throws a mongo error, that authentication failed

Am I trying to authenticate incorrectly, or doing something else wrong? I'm not understanding my mistake.

Here is the error

```
C:\Users\Corey Byrne\Documents\DocuBuilder\Email Project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\base.js:245
    throw message;      
          ^
MongoError: auth failed
    at Object.toError (C:\Users\Corey Byrne\Documents\DocuBuilder\Email Project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\utils.js:110:11)
    at C:\Users\Corey Byrne\Documents\DocuBuilder\Email Project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.js:1128:31
    at C:\Users\Corey Byrne\Documents\DocuBuilder\Email Project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.js:1843:9
    at Server.Base._callHandler (C:\Users\Corey Byrne\Documents\DocuBuilder\Email Project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\base.js:445:41)
    at C:\Users\Corey Byrne\Documents\DocuBuilder\Email Project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\server.js:468:18
    at MongoReply.parseBody (C:\Users\Corey Byrne\Documents\DocuBuilder\Email Project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\responses\mongo_reply.js:68:5)
    at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Corey Byrne\Documents\DocuBuilder\Email Project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\server.js:426:20)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Corey Byrne\Documents\DocuBuilder\Email Project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\connection_pool.js:201:13)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
```

Comment: can you add a stacktrace to the question ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are creating the user in a db called `admin` and then trying to login to a db called `db`.

Answer (score 0):

It fails when you pass in the `db` to connect to in the url. Looks like the authentication is done against the same db. Instead you should do:

```
    const client = await new Promise((res, rej) =>
      MongoClient.connect(
        K2_MONGODB_URL,
        {
          auth: {
            authdb: 'admin'
          },
          useNewUrlParser: true 
        },
        (err, client) => (err ? rej(err) : res(client))
      )
    )
```

where `K2_MONGODB_URL=mongodb://user:password@localhost:27017`